Bigframes package - Problem with Dataframe apply function
I am a new user of bigframes package from googleapis. I am trying to manipulate dataframe loaded from Bigquery.
I was trying to execute some code but I am facing a problem that i am not able to solve.
I am trying to use the apply function on a Dataframe with the parameter axis=1 , but it doesn't seem to work. I always have an error message.
Can you please help me with this?
Thanks.
Code example
# example
def condition(row):
    print(row )
    if 1 <= row["month"] <= 6:
        return f"{row['year']:02}S1{row['CODPY']}{row['CODDE']}"
    else:
        return f"{row['year']:02}S2{row['CODPY']}{row['CODDE']}"

valodetail_df['IDT'] = valodetail_df.apply(condition,axis=1)

Stack trace
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/qback/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bigframes/core/log_adapter.py", line 44, in wrapper
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/qback/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bigframes/dataframe.py", line 3118, in apply
    results = {name: func(col, *args, **kwargs) for name, col in self.items()}
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/qback/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bigframes/dataframe.py", line 3118, in <dictcomp>
    results = {name: func(col, *args, **kwargs) for name, col in self.items()}
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in condition
  File "missing.pyx", line 419, in pandas._libs.missing.NAType.__bool__
TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous
>>> valodetail_df['IDTDCI'] = valodetail_df.apply(condition,axis=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/qback/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bigframes/core/log_adapter.py", line 44, in wrapper
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/qback/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bigframes/dataframe.py", line 3118, in apply
    results = {name: func(col, *args, **kwargs) for name, col in self.items()}
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/qback/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bigframes/dataframe.py", line 3118, in <dictcomp>
    results = {name: func(col, *args, **kwargs) for name, col in self.items()}
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: condition() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'


axis=1 is currently not supported: https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigframes/latest/bigframes.dataframe.DataFrame#bigframes_dataframe_DataFrame_apply
There is a feature request https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery-dataframes/issues/592 for the same.
However for your particular use case it is possible to achieve by other means.
Here is a guess of the kind of DataFrame you are working with:
import bigframes.pandas as bpd

df = bpd.DataFrame({
        "month": [1,3,6,7,12],
        "year":  ["8", "9", "10", "11", "12"],
        "CODPY": ["PY", "PY", "PY", "PY", "PY"],
        "CODDE": ["DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE"],
     })
df

    month   year    CODPY   CODDE
0       1      8       PY      DE
1       3      9       PY      DE
2       6     10       PY      DE
3       7     11       PY      DE
4      12     12       PY      DE

We can use other DataFrame and Series APIs to create the desired column:
condition = (df["month"] >= 1) & (df["month"] <= 6)

s1 = df["year"].str.pad(fillchar='0', width=2) + "S1" + df["CODPY"] + df["CODDE"]

s2 = df["year"].str.pad(fillchar='0', width=2) + "S2" + df["CODPY"] + df["CODDE"]

df['IDT'] = s1.where(condition, s2)
df

   month    year    CODPY   CODDE        IDT
0      1       8       PY      DE   08S1PYDE
1      3       9       PY      DE   09S1PYDE
2      6      10       PY      DE   10S1PYDE
3      7      11       PY      DE   11S2PYDE
4     12      12       PY      DE   12S2PYDE

Hope this helps.

Thank you for answering. It is indeed another way to do it. I guess there is always to have a work-around on the features missing in bigframes package. Looking forward having the feature ready

As of BigQuery DataFrames (bigframes) version 1.6.0 there is now a preview of support for apply with axis=1 making use of BigQuery Remote Functions.
If your function is doing something that couldn't be expressed without an axis=1 function as shown in Shobhit's workaound in https://stackoverflow.com/a/78331896/101923, you can now do the following:
import bigframes

bigframes.__version__
# 1.6.0

import bigframes.pandas as bpd

df = bpd.DataFrame({
        "month": [1,3,6,7,12],
        "year":  ["8", "9", "10", "11", "12"],
        "CODPY": ["PY", "PY", "PY", "PY", "PY"],
        "CODDE": ["DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE"],
     })


# Note: input_types must be a Series.
# Only scalar output types are currently supported.
@bpd.remote_function(input_types=bpd.Series, output_type=str)
def condition(row):
    print(row)
    if 1 <= row["month"] <= 6:
        return f"{row['year']:02}S1{row['CODPY']}{row['CODDE']}"
    else:
        return f"{row['year']:02}S2{row['CODPY']}{row['CODDE']}"


df['IDT'] = df.apply(condition, axis=1)
df





month
year
CODPY
CODDE
IDT




0
1
8
PY
DE
80S1PYDE


1
3
9
PY
DE
90S1PYDE


2
6
10
PY
DE
10S1PYDE


3
7
11
PY
DE
11S2PYDE


4
12
12
PY
DE
12S2PYDE



Note: There are currently (bigframes==1.6.0) limitations to the data types that are supported. Your row can only contain INT64, FLOAT64, BOOL, or STRING columns (source).
